# block in Swift : return error " is not convertible to "

Tags: ios, swift, block, type-alias

I made a mistake but I cannot see how to solve it. I would like to load all the assets from GameScene and send a Bool in a completion method. I use typealias : should it be renamed twice for the two files (gameScene and gameController)?

Then I have got an error on this line `GameScene.loadSceneAssetsWithCompletionHandler{` :

> ((Bool) -> Void) is not convertible to 'GameScene'

Here is the code :

```
    //gameController:
    typealias OnComplete = (Bool) -> ()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        GameScene.loadSceneAssetsWithCompletionHandler{ (success:Bool)->Void in
            println("2/ yes")
            return
        }



    //gameScene : rewrite typealias? 
    typealias OnComplete = (Bool) -> ()

    func loadSceneAssetsWithCompletionHandler( completion:OnComplete ) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), { () -> Void in
            self.loadSceneAssets()

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                println("1/ yes")
                completion(true)
            })//main
        })//global
    }
```

I read some threads that said to add a "return", but it does not solve the error here.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's almost working, but you've got a couple things going wrong here. First of all, you can't redeclare a `typealias`. Second of all you're calling `loadSceneAssetsWithCompletionHandler` as a class function when it's set up as an instance function. Note changes:

```
typealias OnComplete = (Bool) -> ()
class GameController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        GameScene.loadSceneAssetsWithCompletionHandler { success in
            println("2/ yes")
            return
        }
    }

}


class GameScene:  UIViewController {

    func loadSceneAssets() {

    }

    class func loadSceneAssetsWithCompletionHandler( completion:OnComplete ) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0)) {
           let gameScene = GameScene()
           gameScene.loadSceneAssets()

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                println("1/ yes")
                completion(true)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, yes my mistake about the typealias, about the class func, I found a code that initializes the scene in the completion block, and so uses the "+" in objective-c in GameScene, isn't it possible to do the same thing?

Comment: thanks I have got many issues with the class func and the var it contains from outside the class func. So it is better to open a new thread I guess ;) Thanks for the help (edit: which is here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28864146/modify-a-struct-variable-from-a-class-func-in-swift-multiple-errors-frame-a )